# Probability problem with uncertainty

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

In a City there are 2 Taxi companies: Blue and Green.
85% of the Taxis are Green, 15% of the taxis are Blue
A man has been hit by a taxi and he claims the taxi was blue but in tribunal the Judge decides to test him: the man is put in an environment similar to the one of the accident and he is asked to state if the Taxis that pass by are either blue or green.
80% of the time he answers correctly and 20% of the time he fails to recognize the color of the taxi. What's the probability that the taxi who hit the man was actually blue?

The author of the problem says that he used Bayes theorem but I don't understand how to apply it, can you help me?

Comment: This particular problem is well discussed online, [here](https://www.anesi.com/bayes.htm) for instance.